# Hide all classes <table> except the one I click and closest parent div

Tags: jquery

I have an issue where I need to be able to hide all other table's (on click) with the class `.this_table` AND in addition hide the closest parent div `.bootstrap-table`. So far I am able to hide all the other tables, but the parent div remains. I tried several variations of adding `.closest('.bootstrap-table')` but I can't get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<a class="report" data-id="table-javascript-1">link1</a>
<a class="report" data-id="table-javascript-2">link2</a>
<a class="report" data-id="table-javascript-3">link3</a>

<div class="bootstrap-table">
    <table class="this_table" id="table-javascript-1"></table>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-table">
    <table class="this_table" id="table-javascript-2"></table>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-table">
    <table class="this_table" id="table-javascript-3"></table>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '.report', function() {
    $('.this_table').not('#'+$(this).attr('data-id')).closest('.bootstrap-table').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Need to add a line that shows all table then hide()

```js
$(document).on('click', '.report', function() {
  $('.bootstrap-table').show()// add this to show all tables before hiding
  $('.this_table').not('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')).closest('.bootstrap-table').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="report" data-id="table-javascript-1">link1</a>
<a class="report" data-id="table-javascript-2">link2</a>
<a class="report" data-id="table-javascript-3">link3</a>

<div class="bootstrap-table">
  <table class="this_table" id="table-javascript-1">1</table>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-table">
  <table class="this_table" id="table-javascript-2">2</table>
</div>
<div class="bootstrap-table">
  <table class="this_table" id="table-javascript-3">3</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.report', function() {
 $('.bootstrap-table').hide(); 
var tableToShow=$(this).attr('data-id');
$('#'+tableToShow).closest('.bootstrap-table').show(); 
});
```

Here i have hide all the element which has class bootstrap-table and then from **this** i am finding id and show the closest bootstrap-table